# Issue/error only in production, not in local dev. Trying to connect app to heroku (backend) and netlify (frontend)

Tags: mongodb, heroku, configuration, production-environment, netlify

I've hooked up my backend server to Heroku, and my frontend React app to Netlify.

I then try to register/login through the live production environment of the app,

and receive this error:

```
        POST http://localhost:8080/api/auth/login net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

When I register/login through in the local environment, everything works fine.

I believe it's because the site is live, yet it's still going through "localhost"

With that said, I'm not sure how to change it?

If it helps to know the technologies used:
React.js frontend, backend Node.js, Express.js, mongoDB

edit update:
here is my front end login in request code:

```
        export const login = (username, password) => (dispatch) => {
          console.log("logging in with", username, password);
          return fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/auth/login`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              username,
              password,
            }),
          })
            .then((res) => normalizeResponseErrors(res))
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then(({ authToken }) => {
              return storeAuthInfo(authToken, dispatch);      
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              const { code } = err;
              const message =
                code === 401
                  ? "Incorrect username or password"
                  : "Unable to login, please try again";
              dispatch(authError(err));
              return Promise.reject(
                new SubmissionError({
                  _error: message,
                })
              );
            });
        };
```

here is my config.js in front end:

```
            export const API_BASE_URL =
                process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL ||'http://localhost:8080/api';

            export const JWT_SECRET = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
            export const JWT_EXPIRY = process.env.JWT_EXPIRY || '7d';
```

Comment: Can you share the code that is making the POST request?

Comment: Sure, I'm guessing you mean the API call that is in my actions folder. Using react-redux. I just edited the post for you. 
I also added the config file for the front end. Lemme know if you need anything else. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the core of your issue is that your front-end code that you shared (from `config.js`), is building your `API_BASE_URL` like so:

```
export const API_BASE_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL ||'http://localhost:8080/api';
```

This is problematic because `process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL` is an environment variable that will not exist on your front end (in the browser). Environment variables are only usable on the back-end.

This means that your conditional statement will ALWAYS end up setting the `API_BASE_URL` to `http://localhost:8080/api`, even if you're running in production!

Comment: ahh thank you for helping point out the problem! so how would you suggest fixing it?

Comment: actually, I'm not sure about that. I have another project set up the same way that runs fine...?

Comment: Hey there. What I'd recommend is first changing that `API_BASE_URL` variable to the one you want: `https://your-prod-app/blah`, then pushing your changes to Heroku and testing it out. Let me know if that works -- if it does, then you just need to update that URL appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I had my config vars set up for my back end on heroku. However, I did not set them up for my front end on netlify.
I had only assume backends needed to be hooked up with config vars, since that's where the environment variables switch from local to production.

However with React, the frontend config vars needs to be set up as well.